# Xamarin forms - authentication with AAD, tried and failed

Tags: azure, xamarin, oauth-2.0, active-directory

I've been trying to get a Xamarin Forms app to get a token from AAD.

I've tried countless different ways of doing it and they all have problems, some are bugs, some I just haven't been able to figure out.

This link is one of the simplest examples I've come across, yet it fails because it says there's no client secret.

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/07/22/using-adal-3-x-with-xamarin-forms/

When I add the client secret, by modifying the AuthenticationContext like so

```
        AuthenticationContext ac = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");
        ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential("------4ba8-4136-ad1c-f36be878af8a", "-----sDdG4/WZCyYU=");
        AuthenticationResult result = await ac.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", cc);
```

I get a new error saying there is no application matching graph.windows.net in my directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the type of the azure ad application your register is `Native Client Application` , that type application are meant to run on a device and aren't trusted to maintain a secret  .

The code you provide is using [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service) to acquire token , that flow uses app's credentials instead of impersonating a user .

Comment: thanks, I actually figured it out myself in the end, I've got a token now from the client app and am trying to get my head around how to use that to make calls to the API

Comment: In code sample ,it acquire token for [Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api) , you can perform [REST operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/signed-in-user-operations) and carry a valid access token obtained from Azure AD in their Authorization header